# Is there a way to get details of which VM connected to which Log Analytics Workspace using Powershell?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I'm looking for a way to get list of VMs with their respective Log Analytics Workspaces (if that VM is connected to Log Analytics workspace) using PowerShell.

Column 1 should be VM names, Column 2 should be corresponding LA Workspace name.

I'm stuck with it and any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the scripts below:

```
#get all the Log Analytics Workspace 
$all_workspace = Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace


#here, I hard-code a vm name for testing purpose. If you have more VMs, you can modify the code below using loop.

$myvm_name = "vm name"
$myvm_resourceGroup= "resource group name of the vm"

#for windows vm, the value is fixed as below
$extension_name = "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent"

$myvm = Get-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName $myvm_resourceGroup -VMName $myvm_name -Name $extension_name

$workspace_id = ($myvm.PublicSettings | ConvertFrom-Json).workspaceId

#$workspace_id

foreach($w in $all_workspace)
{
if($w.CustomerId.Guid -eq $workspace_id)
  { 
  #here, I just print out the vm name and the connected Log Analytics workspace name
  Write-Output "the vm: $($myvm_name) writes log to Log Analytics workspace named: $($w.name)"
  }
}
```

The test result:

[image]

**Notes of the scripts:**

1.In the script, for testing purpose, I hard-code the vm name / resource group name. If you have more VMs, please modify the scripts accordingly. It's easy to make the change.

2.If the VMs are all windows vm, then keep using the value of the parameter `$extension_name = "MicrosoftMonitoringAgent"`.

3.I just print out the VM name and the connected Log analytics workspace name. You can modify the script accordingly to meet your requirement.

Comment: Your script has worked out beautifully for me, the place I was struggling was, reading that Public settings property, missed out simple trick of converting Json.

Comment: @praveenkrish, could you please accept it as answer as per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Thanks:).